# rails-toastr: add a close button

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, toast, toastr

I'm using the rails-toastr gem (Rails 5.0.0.1) and I want to add a close button to the toasters.

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#quick-start) and added links to `toastr.css` and `toastr.js` in `application.html.erb`. Then I created the two files under `app/assets/stylesheets` and `app/assets/javascripts` respectively and in the latter I added the line:

```
toastr.options.closeButton = true;
```

but the toasters don't come up.

I have this method in `application_helper.rb` (which I call in `application.html.erb`):

```
def custom_bootstrap_flash
  flash_messages = []
  flash.each do |type, message|
    type = 'success' if type == 'notice'
    type = 'error'   if type == 'alert'
    text = "<script>toastr.#{type}('#{message}');</script>"
    flash_messages << text.html_safe if message
  end
  flash_messages.join("\n").html_safe
end
```

but without the two assets, this works fine (but no close button of course).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this Upwork freelancer](https://www.upwork.com/o/profiles/users/_~01f64a33cefe90dc50), we went for a solution similar to [Beengie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52237972/5903989). We added a `toastr_override.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts/helpers/` with the following:

```
//= require toastr/toastr
toastr.options = Object.assign({}, toastr.options, {
    closeButton: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the options in your application.js file, or in your specific js/coffee files if you want other options for specific pages.

application.js

```
...
//= require toastr

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "progressBar": true,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};
```

A full list of options for toastr are found [here](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html). Just run the demo, and there will be an output file showing the options you selected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but it looks like [CodeSeven/toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toast) out of date and no longer maintained.

I had the same issue as you have but I solved this issue by using another [toastr gem](https://github.com/d4be4st/toastr_rails) which is currently fully functional and can "see" toastr options. I hope it will help you or any other who would face with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Never use this approach, using `html_safe` is a security issue and `rubocop` will complain about your code, ie:

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:10:30: C: Rails/OutputSafety: Tagging a string as html safe may be a security risk.
      flash_messages << text.html_safe if message
```

Instead follow these steps:

Add an helper:

```
module FooHelper
  def toastr_flash_class(type)
    case type
    when "alert"
      "toastr.error"
    when "notice"
      "toastr.success"
    else
      "toastr.info"
    end
  end
end
```

create a partial, for example `_toaster.html.erb`

```
<%= content_tag(:script) do %>
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <%= toastr_flash_class("#{type}") %>('<%= message %>')
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

call your partial from your layouts, or from your views:

```
<%= render 'layouts/shared/toastr' %>
```